# C++ - Overloading operator>> and processing input using C-style strings

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays, c-strings

I'm working on an assignment where we have to create a "MyInt" class that can handle larger numbers than regular ints. We only have to handle non-negative numbers. I need to overload the `>>` operator for this class, but I'm struggling to do that.

I'm not allowed to `#include <string>`.

Is there a way to:

a. Accept input as a C-style string
b. Parse through it and check for white space and non-numbers (i.e. if the prompt is cin >> x >> y >> ch, and the user enters 1000 934H, to accept that input as two MyInts and then a char).

I'm assuming it has something to do with `peek()` and `get()`, but I'm having trouble figuring out where they come in.

I'd rather not know *exactly* how to do it! Just point me in the right direction.

Here's my constructor, so you can get an idea for what the class is (I also have a conversion constructor for `const char *`.

```
MyInt::MyInt (int n)
{
   maxsize = 1;

   for (int i = n; i > 9; i /= 10) {
      // Divides the number by 10 to find the number of times it is divisible; that is the length
      maxsize++;
   }

   intstring = new int[maxsize];

   for (int j = (maxsize - 1); j >= 0; j--) {
      // Copies the integer into an integer array by use of the modulus operator
       intstring[j] = n % 10;
       n = n / 10;
   }
}
```

Thanks! Sorry if this question is vague, I'm still new to this. Let me know if I can provide any more info to make the question clearer.

Answer (score 2):

So what you basically want is to parse a `const char*` to retrieve a integer number inside it, and ignore all whitespace(+others?) characters.

Remember that characters like `'1'` or `'M'` or even `' '` are just integers, mapped to the ASCII table. So you can easily convert a character from its notation human-readable (`'a'`) to its value in memory. There are plenty of sources on ascii table and chars in C/C++ so i'll let you find it, but you should get the idea. In C/C++, **characters are numbers** (of type `char`).

With this, you then know you can perform operations on them, like addition, or comparison.

Last thing when dealing with C-strings : they are null-terminated, meaning that the character `'\0'` is placed right after their last used character.

Comment: How is it possible to parse a `const char*` with a return type of `istream&`?

Comment: @user1888527 I thought you wanted to take `const char*` input, that's why I focused on it. I'll edit my response later for `istream`, no time for that at the moment sorry. If you want to try yourself, the principle is basically the same as for C-strings, but with the istream interface.